# ASP recordset fileds are empty at second utilisation

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, recordset

Does anyone know why this statement

```
Response.write(rs.Fields.Item("password")&" ; "&rs.Fields.Item("password"))
```

Do this :

```
myPass ;
```

It's very strange and I'm looking for a solution since this morning. It's making me crazy because the result of this is that this codntion :

```
if rs("password") = rs("password") then
```

is False !

EDIT :

After other test, i have made an other discover :

```
Response.write(rs.Fields.Item("name")&" ; "&rs.Fields.Item("name"))
```

do :

```
amdin ; admin
```

And if i change "password" by his ordinal index it doing the same displays :

```
myPass ;
```

.

EDIT : the related code :

```
Set Conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Conn.Open "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver}; SERVER=localhost; DATABASE=crm_sandbox; UID=root;PASSWORD=tahina; OPTION=3" 

if Request.Form("login") <> "" or Request.Form("mdp") <> "" or Request.Form("redirect") <> "" then
    Response.write(Request.Form("mdp")&" ; "&Request.Form("login")&" ; "&Request.Form("redirect")&"<br>")
    if Request.Form("login") = "" then
        rapport = "<p style='color: red; font-weight: bold;'>Erreur : Veuillez remplir votre nom d'utilisateur.</p>"
    elseif Request.Form("mdp") = "" then
        rapport = "<p style='color: red; font-weight: bold;'>Erreur : Veuillez remplir votre mot de passe.</p>"
    elseif Request.Form("login") <> "" and Request.Form("mdp") <> "" then
        sql = "SELECT id, mdp, nom, initiales, couleur, droit FROM connection WHERE nom='"&Request.Form("login")&"';"
        Set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
        rs.open sql, conn

        if rs.eof then
            rapport = "<p style='color: red; font-weight: bold;'>Erreur : Nom d'utilisateur inconnu.</p>"
        elseif rs("mdp") <> Request.Form("mdp") then
            rapport = "<p style='color: red; font-weight: bold;'>Erreur : Mot de passe incorect.</p>"
        elseif Request.Form("mdp") = rs("mdp") then
            Session("util_id") = rs("id")
            Session("util_nom") = rs("nom")
            Session("util_couleur") = rs("couleur")
            Session("util_initiales") = rs("initiales")
            Session("util_droit") = rs("droit")
            Session.Timeout = 660 'On créer une session de 11 heures
            rapport = "<p style='color: green; font-weight: bold;'>Vous êtes à présent connecté !</p>"

            if Request.Form("redirect") <> "" then
                rapport = rapport&"<p>Vous allez être rédirigé vers votre page dans 3 secondes</p>"
            end if
        end if
    end if
end if
```

Comment: That's interesting. What happens if you retrieve the recordset column values by ordinal (index). For example, `If rs(3) = rs(3) Then`.

Comment: I have edited my question for more tests

Comment: Hmm. Can we see everything related to the `Connection` and `Recordset` objects? Creation, SQL query, etc.

Comment: Edited with my code. Sorry some part of the code is with frensh language.

Comment: Check the password field is not null. `Reasponse.write(isNull(rs.Fields.Item("password")))

Comment: He is not null, there is the value "myPass" like the line "myPass ; " show's it. The problem is that the value seems to disappear... So at this time i have passed throw the problem by puting the value in a variable. But this bug still interesting me ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've actually had this issue before, when the page made it's first run, the first value of the recordset(value) returns a value, but upon second reading of recordset(value) it returned null. Or excactly what is happening with your current set up.

This is not actually a very well known issue, but there are still several support forums and questions answer along the same lines.

[Example Page 1](http://bytes.com/topic/sql-server/answers/909000-recordset-becomes-null-after-first-read-use)
[Example Page 2](http://p2p.wrox.com/classic-asp-databases/64892-values-recordset-lost-after-reading.html)

There are acouple *theories* that could cause this, such as, not having the correct data type in the table column data type specifier. A glitch in the recordset object that only returns the value once, and thus, must be stored in an object instead.

Because it is the second calling of the same variable that is returning `Null`

E.g.

```
'  [Good Read-out] - object empties itself
if rs( "password")_
= rs("password") then
' [Bad Read-out] - object no longer contains values.
```

This is NOT a blanket statement occurrence, this is an anomaly, a glitch, something that doesn't have a solid reason behind it's minimal prevalence beyond the ghost in the machine.

To fix this:

Only read out the variables from the current record **ONE** time. This will not allow the object to empty and thus you can compare your checks later on in your code without any fuss.

```
Set Conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Conn.Open "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver}; SERVER=localhost; DATABASE=crm_sandbox; UID=root;PASSWORD=tahina; OPTION=3" 

if Request.Form("login") <> "" or Request.Form("mdp") <> "" or Request.Form("redirect") <> "" then
    Response.write(Request.Form("mdp")&" ; "&Request.Form("login")&" ; "&Request.Form("redirect")&"<br>")
    if Request.Form("login") = "" then
        rapport = "<p style='color: red; font-weight: bold;'>Erreur : Veuillez remplir votre nom d'utilisateur.</p>"
    elseif Request.Form("mdp") = "" then
        rapport = "<p style='color: red; font-weight: bold;'>Erreur : Veuillez remplir votre mot de passe.</p>"
    elseif Request.Form("login") <> "" and Request.Form("mdp") <> "" then
        sql = "SELECT id, mdp, nom, initiales, couleur, droit FROM connection WHERE nom='"&Request.Form("login")&"';"
        Set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
        rs.open sql, conn



        '------------------------------------------------
        'Place record set values in variables first. 
        Dim rMDP, rID, rNom, rCouleur, rInit, rDroit
        rMDP = rs("mdp")
        rID = rs("id")
        rNom = rs("nom")
        rCouleur = rs("couleur")
        rInit = rs("initiales")
        rDroit = rs("droit")
         '------------------------------------------------



        if rs.eof then
            rapport = "<p style='color: red; font-weight: bold;'>Erreur : Nom d'utilisateur inconnu.</p>"
        elseif rMDP <> Request.Form("mdp") then
            rapport = "<p style='color: red; font-weight: bold;'>Erreur : Mot de passe incorect.</p>"
        elseif Request.Form("mdp") = rMDP then
            Session("util_id") = rID
            Session("util_nom") = rNom
            Session("util_couleur") = rCouleur
            Session("util_initiales") = rInit
            Session("util_droit") = rDroit
            Session.Timeout = 660 'On créer une session de 11 heures
            rapport = "<p style='color: green; font-weight: bold;'>Vous êtes à présent connecté !</p>"

            if Request.Form("redirect") <> "" then
                rapport = rapport&"<p>Vous allez être rédirigé vers votre page dans 3 secondes</p>"
            end if
        end if
    end if
end if
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have made the same that you propose in your fix and it's runing good. So in finality, the answer of my question is : because Microsoft...

Comment: And I have not the choice of the technologie I have to use ><'

Comment: I can't say I've ever had this problem but then again I use `data = Recordset.GetRows()` to work with an Array instead. In less laborious than `ADODB.Recordset` and for simple iteration of results it's more efficient. My guess would be the type of cursor is the problem, by default `Recordset.Open()` uses a `adOpenForwardOnly` (forward only recordset).

Comment: @EmrysMyrooin Would also take a look at [CursorTypeEnum - ADO API on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms681771(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Yeap i have looked around this and it's probably the source of my problem but i haven't looked for this more .

Comment: @Rich Man and you did not noticed completely redundant "if Request.Form("login") = "" then" and so on checks? Within original first IF statement all those varues has been checked already and if any of those things are empty none of the others will be ever reached!

Comment: @AllBlond Oh I noticed, but the question wasn't about optimizing the OP's code, or checking `if` statements. It was about fixing the OP's recordset handling. So that's how I approached it.

Comment: @Rich: you are pro and as such should point it out or at least not have it in your code. But anyway those extra if's will not do anything but slow page processing.

Comment: Kind of agree with Rich to be honest @AllBlond. The question wasn't "How can I optimise my code?". Personally I've found it easier just to provide a solution within the framework of the OPs code rather than changing it too much as this can confuse the issue more.

Comment: Although after all that it looks like the actual issue was the fact he was using a *Forward Only* cursor type.

Answer (score 0):

Always retrieve the recordset values and place them in the variables, then manipulate them. I learned some strange issues with rs values in first days I started using classic ASP some 15 years ago.

Comment: I just saw the question recently. However, my answer is to ALWAYS fetch it, not just in particular case of comparison. Glad you solved it.

Comment: @Dalibor If you read my answer entirely, I was also promoting to ALWAYS fetch it, I was using the comparison as an example of why it did not work for the OP because that was in the initial question.