# ASP content display issue

Tags: asp-classic

I moved my site to another hosting, but the language menu `<a>` tags between the content of the database does not print between the label. But inside the `href` parameter it draws the same query.

When I examined the output of the code:

[Output code picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gUzoj.png)

Below is my code in that line:

```
<ul class="headerLanguage"><li><a href="/?lang=<%=Session("lang")%>"><%=Session("lang")%><img alt="" title="" src="/images/icon/08.png" /></a><ul><%
Set a = SQL.Execute("SELECT kisa FROM diller WHERE kisa<>'"& Session("lang") &"'")
Do while not a.Eof %><li><a href="/?lang=<%=a("kisa")%>"><%=a("kisa")%></a></li><% a.MoveNext:Loop
a.Close
Set a = Nothing %></ul></li></ul>
```

When I delete the query inside the `href` parameter, the other query runs and the content is appearing.

My application is Classic ASP, but I did not have a problem with my old site, why was this so? How can I solve?

I'm grateful for your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP recordset fileds are empty at second utilisation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23340622/asp-recordset-fileds-are-empty-at-second-utilisation)

Comment: Read the [ADODB documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/execute-method-ado-connection?view=sql-server-2017) to understand how `ADODB.Connection` `Execute()` method works - *"The returned Recordset object is always a **read-only, forward-only cursor**"*.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this problem before. I'm not sure exactly why it happens (hopefully someone else can explain), but sometimes if you reference data directly from a recordset multiple times it can return an empty value. The solution that worked for me was to assign the data to a variable first and reference the variable instead. Try this:

```
<ul class="headerLanguage">
    <li>
        <a href="/?lang=<%=Session("lang")%>"><%=Session("lang")%>
            <img alt="" title="" src="/images/icon/08.png" />
        </a>
        <ul><%
        Dim a, kisa    
        Set a = SQL.Execute("SELECT kisa FROM diller WHERE kisa<>'"& Session("lang") &"'")
            Do while not a.Eof
                kisa = a("kisa") %>
                <li><a href="/?lang=<%=kisa%>"><%=kisa%></a></li><%  
            a.MoveNext:Loop
            a.Close
        Set a = Nothing 
        %></ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: but I have this issue my product page. How to fix this issue?  Please Help Me.

Comment: @E. ÇAPAN My answer is more of a hack than a solution because I don't really understand what is causing the issue. I just know that if you use variables to store recordset data the issue goes away. It might be that you're not dimming your recordset objects, and this is causing issues in a different version of IIS being used by your new host, but I really don't know for sure, sorry. Hopefully someone else can shed more light on this and provide a better solution.

Comment: thank you for answer. I so need true answer. I am very important this issue. Please help.

Comment: @Adam you really need to start checking and flagging duplicates. The reason is going to be because the OP is opening a Forward-Only recordset cursor as that is the default when calling a the `Execute()` method of the `ADODB.Connection` object.

Comment: @Lankymart Sorry about that. I did do a quick search before answering but didn't find any answers hinting towards the cursor (or more likely I just didn't looking hard enough). I had no idea the default cursor behaved like that. That's very handy to know, especially since I've had this same issue myself in the past. Thank you.

Comment: @Adam to be honest, I've rarely come across it because I use `GetRows()` to return a 2-dimensional array and close the recordset object and release the memory as quick as I can. Never like working with the `ADODB.Recordset` it's clunky and less efficient, the only real use is if you want to get meta data such as field names, column data types etc or if you using them in a disconnected state.